# New Attribute values don't show on product page

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, custom-attributes, configurable-swatches

I have a problem with the values of attributes in my Magento installation.
I have created an attribute with the weight of the products and have created some configurable products with these attribute and those were shown correctly on the webshop.
Today I tried to add new values to the same attributes, and I tried to create new products with more values (some values are the values inserted today, and some values older).
Basically, on the product page only the old one and not the new values are shown. Is there someone who knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running below commands:

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Also make sure you have assigned this attribute to attribute set.